# No issue of techum during kriyas yam suf

Tags: halacha, midrash, yetziat-mitzrayim, miracle, techum

The Torah [says](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.14.22) that the sea formed a wall to the left and right of the Jews. The Midrash [clarifies](https://www.sefaria.org/Mekhilta_d'Rabbi_Yishmael.14.22.2) that it became a solid wall.

The Chasam Sofer (to be precise, [his grandson](https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%A8_(1850))), to resolve a different issue, [says](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35893&pgnum=100) that since the Jews were surrounded by walls, there was [no prohibition](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.397.3) of techumin.

I could understand this if they were literally surrounded by walls, but according to my understanding having a wall to the left and right isn't called enclosed. Why would this suffice to avoid the prohibition of techumin? There was a breach in front of them and behind them. I recall there's an opinion somewhere that the sea split to form a semi circle, but I don't think that would help.

(Yes I'm aware this is drush not halacha)

Comment: a sharp turn in a road disqualifies it from being a public thoroughfare and with walls is a reshus hayachid deoraisa, but the rabbis instituted a beam or a lechi. iruvin were instituted by Shlomo hamelech after krias Yam suf  It could be according to the Rambam pirkei avos chapter 5 they went in a U shape that turned sharply which was a reshus hayachid in those days

Comment: @user15464 why not post that as an answer? But to clarify: when you say a road with a sharp turn and walls, you mean two walls?

Comment: Don't know if this helps but someone told me there's a Midrash that the sea wasn't split all the way, rather just until in front of the Jews. This would make them enclosed on three sides.

Comment: I don't know how deep the _Yam Suf_ was at the time or how steep the walls were. (Perhaps [this guy](http://migdolbook.com/crossing-red-sea-aqaba-no.html) does.) And I'm also not well enough versed in _eruvei t'chumin_ to know if the same _m'chitza_ rules apply to it as to _chatzeros_. But if it was and if they do, perhaps [the banks constituted](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=8Z_n07aJGVYC&pg=PA89) the "front" and "back" walls according to the Chasam Sofer.

Comment: Why would it matter that there was no prohibition of Techumin? They weren't commanded in Techumin for another month.

Comment: @DonielF the Chasam Sofer says that the tribe of Yosef kept Shabbos/yom tov for the entire Egyptian exile, and in their merit Hashem made a miracle such that they wouldn't (albeit b'ones) break techumin. This is what the verse means when it days וירא הים וינוס, and the Midrash says it saw Yosef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some say that in fact they were surrounded in front as well, as the sea didn’t split all the way. It would gradually split in front of them as they walked. This created three walls, with the area behind them open (**Rabbeinu Bachaye** to **Exodus** [13:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.13.17?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Shemot.13.17.2&lang2=bi), brought by **Yalkut Me’am Loez** *Shemos* Chapter 15 *s.v.* הנס השביעי, and **Rabbeinu Bachaye** to **Avos** 5:5, explaining an unknown *Midrash* (see **Radak** to **Psalms** [114:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.114.3?lang=bi&p2=Radak_on_Psalms.114.3.1&lang2=bi))).

According to Torah law, a three-walled enclosure is considered a private domain (entirely enclosed) (**Mishneh Torah** *Hilchos Shabbos* [17:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Sabbath.17.2)), to the point that there’s no issue of *techumin* (as brought in the question from the **Mishnah Berurah**).